# When penicillin was initially introduced, was it effective against all gram positives?

Tags: 20th-century, medicine

I'm trying to investigate the history of resistance. Just how good was penicillin when it first emerged? Were there any gram positives it couldn't get?

Comment: Doesn't look like a stupid question to me!

Comment: Oh, that's mainly for the StackOverflow, where my questions are pretty basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it would not have been effective against everything.**

For instance, bacteria with with sufficient [β-lactamase](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Beta-lactamase) production would have been resistant. This enzyme is very ancient as well, having evolved a *billion* years ago. Thus, while I don't know of any species that was resistant as a whole, ***individual* resistant bacterium existed** before penicillin's clinical adoption. This was proven in the [Lederberg Experiment](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evosite/evo101/IIIC1bLederberg.shtml), which showed that resistant bacteria existed in a colony *before* contact with penicillin, as opposed to appearing as a mutation *afterwards*.

What *is* clear, however, is that the efficacy of penicillin has been degrading. When initially made available for general anti-bacterial use, *penicillin was incredibly effective* against [staphylococci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staphylococcus) and [streptococci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streptococcus), two very prolific causes of infections. It didn't last - as early as 1946, reports of penicillin resistant [Staphylococcus aureus](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Staphylococcus_aureus) were appearing around the world, and now most strains of the bacteria have became resistant. By the 1960s it had evolved into the scourge known as [MSRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methicillin-resistant_Staphylococcus_aureus).

> When penicillin was introduced in 1944 over 94% of Staphylococcus aureus isolates were susceptible; by 1950 half were resistant. By 1960 many hospitals had outbreaks of virulent multi-resistant S. aureus.
>
> **<sub>- Livermore, David M. "Antibiotic Resistance in Staphylococci." *International Journal of Antimicrobial Agents* 16 (2000): 3-10.</sub>**

Comment: Cool. Didn't realize how prevalent resistant bacteria already were - resistance is both a selection and evolution process, then.

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion "natural" selection *is* a key part of the evolutionary process after all ;)

Comment: Bacteria are so small, prolific, and short-lived that *any* anti-bacterial in the long run is doomed to be evolved around.